# Given a char array with words in it, find all 'a' characters and replace with xyz. Modify the input array, do not create a copy of the array

Tags: string, complexity-theory

This is an interview question. I wanted to know if instead of 'a' we want to replace 'xyz' does that mean we have to create 2 extra space or can I increase the size at that particular index? What could be the most efficient complexity of it in terms of running time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complexity will be `O(strlen(in))`, optimization is going to be focused on the constant.

I've come up with [a simple, relatively efficient implementation](http://ideone.com/nAgej).  Note that since we are told to build the result in-place, we MUST assume that the original buffer is large enough to accommodate the growth.

Going to test it on ideone.

Done: http://ideone.com/nAgej

Comment: @Ben Whats in? and what do you think of the first question?

Comment: @Richa: It's an array.  Arrays don't have constant-time insertion.  And "in" is the string you're given.

Comment: @Ben `while (*p) p2 += ((*(p++)) == 'a') ? 3: 1;` by this did you mean `while (*p) { p2 += ((*(p++)) == 'a') ? 3: 1; }` ?

Comment: @Richa, there's no difference.

Comment: @Ben I am not very good with pointers hence not able to understand this while statement. According to me if the content of the location p points to is 'a' then p2=s+3 ?

Comment: @Richa: Pointer `p` is moving through the input string.  `p2` is moving through the output string.  Every time an `a` is found in the input, the output gets three longer.  Other characters make the output one longer.

Comment: @Ben How is output getting longer? There is just 1 array and p2 is a pointer. Does adding numbers to pointer, increase the size of the array it is pointing to?

Comment: @Richa: The size of the buffer is irrelevant, as long as it's "big enough".  We're interested in the used part of the buffer.  After the first while loop, the part used by the input stretches from `s` to `p`, the part needed by the output stretches from `s` to `p2`.

Answer (score 4):

To do this efficiently, you want to scan forwards through the string counting the 'a's, then scan backwards copying the characters directly to their correct final position while injecting 'xyz's as necessary:

- move a pointer through the string from the start until you find the end

  - as it moves, count the number of 'a's
- while the `a_count` is not 0, move the pointer backwards through the string

  - if the pointer isn't on an 'a', copy the character under the pointer to an address `a_count * 2` characters forwards of the pointer
  - else (you're pointer is to an 'a'), copy 'xyz' to address `pointer + --a_count * 2`

This approach is O(N) where N is the number of characters in the string.

Comment: Almost exactly what I did, except I used two pointers and no count.

Comment: @Ben: yes, I just had a look - nice and probably faster. Did you copy the NUL properly though? - might explain the couple seemingly "garbage" characters in your test output... (I didn't check your code carefully enough to answer that question myself)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple. Just needs 2 passes and is O(n).

1. Count # of 'a' in string
2. Using length of original string and # of 'a', compute the limits of the modified string
3. Do a reverse pass on the string and replace 'a' by 'xyz'

Here is a C implementation of this. Note that I have made the replaceable string a variable in `replace` you can change it to anything else of any length, just make sure that the array has enough space.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char arr[1024];
    char search='a', *replace="xyz";

    fgets(arr,1023/strlen(replace),stdin);
    if (arr[strlen(arr)-1]=='\n')
        arr[strlen(arr)-1]='\0';
    puts(arr);

    int i, j, k, offset, target;
    for (i=offset=0; i<strlen(arr); ++i)
        if (arr[i]==search)
            offset+=strlen(replace)-1;

    target = strlen(arr)+offset;
    for (i=strlen(arr); i>=0; --i) {
        if (arr[i]!=search)
            arr[target--] = arr[i];
        else {
            target -= strlen(replace);
            strncpy(&arr[target+1],replace,strlen(replace));
        }
    }

    puts(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It could be O(N), but you call `strlen` too many times for it to be.

Comment: Well, a good compiler would be able to cache the return of strlen(). Besides, the code was for illustrating my idea, one can always have a 2 more variables for strlen(arr) and strlen(replace).